# put special character by code in yaml file

Tags: special-characters, yaml, sonata-admin, symfony-2.3

Working with Symfony 2 and Sonata Admin Bundle. Refactored translation from xliff to yml. There is a home sign `⌂` in translation file which was saved as `&#8962;` in xliff file.

I can save it as unicode symbol but I cannot find a way to save it as code as it was done in xliff. Tried:

```
 breadcrumb.link_dashboard: &#8962;
 breadcrumb.link_dashboard: "&#8962;"
 breadcrumb.link_dashboard: '&#8962;'
 breadcrumb.link_dashboard: \&#8962;
 breadcrumb.link_dashboard: \u&#8962;
 breadcrumb.link_dashboard: \u#8962
 breadcrumb.link_dashboard: \x#8962
 breadcrumb.link_dashboard: \u8962
 breadcrumb.link_dashboard: \x8962
```

Google does not help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tried to place the ⌂ sign directly into the yaml file. And that works fine.

Otherwise it seems that the char like: `&#8962;` gets escaped and will be displayed as html entities.

You can also add the one of the following line into your template

```
{{ admin.trans('testvalue')|raw }}

{{ 'testvalue'|trans({}, 'your_translation_domain')|raw }}
```

Important is to call the | raw method on the value. Otherwise twig will escape it.

Comment: So the answer would be that it is not possible to have character saved by code in yml file as opposed to xliff file where this is possible?

Comment: Yes it seems so. It is possible to set the value "&#8962;" into the yaml file. But notice to use semicolon. Otherwise yaml parser think its an comment. The problem is that the &#8962; value gets escaped when rendering throw twig.